# How to pass row id to render row react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Thanks in advance.
Now iam able pass value to render row method and my component get render. I need to style more with my list item such as alternate background color change. So how do i get the row id and pass it into render row helper class.

```
 componentWillMount(){   

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged:(r1,r2) => r1!=r2            
    }) 
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2','row 3', 'row 4'])        
}

  renderRow(value){ 
    return <EachItem item ={value}/>
}

render(){
    return(
        <View>           
            <ListView
                dataSource = {this.dataSource}
                renderRow  = {this.renderRow} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, **renderRow** takes four paramaters: **rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow**. **rowID** is what you need.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow

Example:

```
renderRow((rowData, sectionId, rowId, highlightRow) => {
   console.log(rowId)
   //do your application's logic here
})`
```